# Set size of a cygwin terminal window

Tags: perl, terminal, cygwin, ansi-escape, mintty

I have a small perl script, which is executed in a cygwin terminal and prints out a formatted table.
On Default window size, cygwin will insert an line break if the text gets too long and thereby destroy the format of my table.
Is there a way from my perl script to set the cygwin window to a bigger size to avoid that kind of problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using mintty as your terminal emulator (it has been the default
terminal emulator for Cygwin for the past couple of years), you can use [ANSI
escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to manipulate the terminal.

You can test this by running the following snippet of Perl code to change the size of your terminal emulator window:

```
# If terminal supports ANSI escape sequences
$lines = 80;
$columns = 100;
print "\e[8;$lines;${columns}t";
```

Note: This doesn't work if run while in a `screen` window and I don't know why. According to the `screen` man page, this escape sequence should be supported.

### Explanation

The syntax of ANSI escape sequences isn’t the easiest to read but here’s the
documentation that provides the basis of the above sequence.

The `\e` prints an Escape character which begins the ANSI escape sequence.
This is also known as the **Control Sequence Introducer (CSI)**.

The specific sequence ending with `t` comes from this [List of xterm control
sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

```
CSI Ps ; Ps ; Ps t
          Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions).
          These controls may be disabled using the allowWindowOps
          resource.  Valid values for the first (and any additional
          parameters) are:
…
Ps = 8  ;  height ;  width -> Resize the text area to given
          height and width in characters.  Omitted parameters reuse the
          current height or width.  Zero parameters use the display's
          height or width.
```

Comment: I had expected this was impossible but it works in my Cygwin. Wow.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer Until I tried it, I wasn't sure which of xterm's control sequences were supported by mintty. In any case, I was fairly certain that the resizing wouldn't work with `cmd.exe` -- and it didn't.

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to be running this from a shortcut where you could add flags to the `mintty` command, you can set the size then. The benefit is that it looks smoother without the twitchy resize.

```
$ /cygdrive/c/tools/cygwin/bin/mintty.exe --help
Usage: mintty [OPTION]... [ PROGRAM [ARG]... | - ]

Start a new terminal session running the specified program or the user's shell.
If a dash is given instead of a program, invoke the shell as a login shell.

Options:
  -c, --config FILE     Load specified config file (cf. -C or -o ThemeFile)
  -e, --exec ...        Treat remaining arguments as the command to execute
  -h, --hold never|start|error|always  Keep window open after command finishes
  -p, --position X,Y    Open window at specified coordinates
  -p, --position center|left|right|top|bottom  Open window at special position
  -p, --position @N     Open window on monitor N
  -s, --size COLS,ROWS  Set screen size in characters (also COLSxROWS)
  -s, --size maxwidth|maxheight  Set max screen size in given dimension
  -t, --title TITLE     Set window title (default: the invoked command) (cf. -T)
  -w, --window normal|min|max|full|hide  Set initial window state
  -i, --icon FILE[,IX]  Load window icon from file, optionally with index
  -l, --log FILE|-      Log output to file or stdout
      --nobidi|--nortl  Disable bidi (right-to-left support)
  -o, --option OPT=VAL  Set/Override config file option with given value
  -B, --Border frame|void  Use thin/no window border
  -R, --Reportpos s|o   Report window position (short/long) after exit
      --nopin           Make this instance not pinnable to taskbar
  -D, --daemon          Start new instance with Windows shortcut key
  -H, --help            Display help and exit
  -V, --version         Print version information and exit
See manual page for further command line options and configuration.
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need Perl, you can do the same in Bash:

```
echo -en "\e[8;35;100t";
```

Or why not a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# minsize - A TTY re-size escape sequence for use with mintty Cygwin
# Usage: minsize <width> <height>
WIDTH=$1
HEIGHT=$2
echo -en "\e[8;${HEIGHT};${WIDTH}t";
```

Note, that on other *nixes there is `ttysize` available.